# Why cant I restrict command use for my bot - discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```
'''
@client.event
@commands.has_role('xrole')
async def on_message(message):
#Commands

  if message.content.startswith("!set"):
    credits_message = message.content.split(" ", 2)

    user_name = credits_message[1]
    credit_add_amount = credits_message[2]

    db[user_name] = int(credit_add_amount)   

    #DB Stuff
    await message.channel.send(user_name + "has been set with " + credit_add_amount + ", For further credit adgustment use !add")

 
'''
```

For some reason Users with or without the xrole can acces the bot even with the @commands restriction

[image: user without xrole]

User without xrole^

[image: user with xrole]

user with xrole ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly don't use `on_message` for commands, it's much better to use `@bot.command`

second: this code should work well for you

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("xrole")
async def role_check(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('''you have the role "xrole"''')


@role_check.error
async def info_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, (commands.MissingRole, commands.MissingAnyRole)):
        await ctx.channel.send('''you do not have the role "xrole"''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Checks` are for `Commands`, **not** for `Events`, so the `has_role` decorator will never be used. You should be using commands instead of manually parsing everything in `on_message` anyways, it makes a lot of stuff way less cumbersome.

Here's an explanation from the docs how to make proper commands instead: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html